# Linux shell - unexpected error

Tags: shell-script, find, rename

I'm new to the linux & command world. I have two directories, one called `pasta` (which contains 3 files) and another one called `pasta2` (with nothing inside). I'm trying to move all 3 files from `pasta` to `pasta2` with the command find. But i get the error bellow. Any suggestion?

Command:

```
find pasta -type f -exec mv pasta2 {} \;
```

and i get this output:

```
mv: cannot overwrite non-directory `pasta/tmp3' with directory `pasta2'
mv: cannot overwrite non-directory `pasta/tmp1' with directory `pasta2'
mv: cannot overwrite non-directory `pasta/tmp2' with directory `pasta2'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the syntax for `mv` wrong. It should be:

```
mv source destination
```

You are running

```
mv destination source
```

Therefore, the `find` command is actually running

```
mv pasta2 pasta/tmp3
mv pasta2 pasta/tmp2
mv pasta2 pasta/tmp1
```

It is complaining that you are trying to overwrite (`mv`) a directory with a regular file. What you actually want to do is

```
find pasta -type f -exec mv {} pasta2 \;
```

This will execute

```
mv pasta/tmp3 pasta2
mv pasta/tmp2 pasta2 
mv pasta/tmp1 pasta2
```

which should run with no errors.